# EditText not showing keyboard when tapped in Flutter AndroidView

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-platform-channel

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall; 
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import static io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.BinaryMessenger;
import io.flutter.plugin.platform.PlatformView;

public class FlutterTextView implements PlatformView, MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private final EditText textView;
    private final MethodChannel methodChannel;

    FlutterTextView(Context context, BinaryMessenger messenger, int id) {
        textView = new EditText(context);
        methodChannel = new MethodChannel(messenger, "plugins.cjs.test/textview_" + id);
        methodChannel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView() {
        return textView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMethodCall(MethodCall methodCall, MethodChannel.Result result) {
        switch (methodCall.method) {
            case "setText":
                setText(methodCall, result);
                break;
            default:
                result.notImplemented();
        }

    }

    private void setText(MethodCall methodCall, Result result) {
        String text = (String) methodCall.arguments;
        textView.setText(text);
        result.success(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {}
}
```

This is the Android platform code. The soft keyboard can not show when embed the EditText AndroidView in Flutter widget. Local Flutter version is 1.2.1.

> Flutter 1.2.1 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
>   Framework • revision 8661d8aecd (3 weeks ago) • 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
>   Engine • revision 3757390fa4
>   Tools • Dart 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)